# Why am I getting different results when using a list comprehension with coroutines with asyncio?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I initially had some code that aggregated results into a list.  When I refactored this code to use a list comphrehension, I am getting unexpected results:

```
import asyncio

@asyncio.coroutine
def coro():
    return "foo"


# Writing the code without a list comp works,
# even with an asyncio.sleep(0.1).
@asyncio.coroutine
def good():
    yield from asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    result = []
    for i in range(3):
        current = yield from coro()
        result.append(current)
    return result


# Using a list comp without an async.sleep(0.1)
# works.
@asyncio.coroutine
def still_good():
    return [(yield from coro()) for i in range(3)]


# Using a list comp along with an asyncio.sleep(0.1)
# does _not_ work.
@asyncio.coroutine
def huh():
    yield from asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    return [(yield from coro()) for i in range(3)]


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
print(loop.run_until_complete(good()))
print(loop.run_until_complete(still_good()))
print(loop.run_until_complete(huh()))
```

If I run this code I get this output:

```
$ python3.4 /tmp/test.py
['foo', 'foo', 'foo']
['foo', 'foo', 'foo']
<generator object <listcomp> at 0x104eb1360>
```

Why do I get different results for third `huh()` function?

Comment: [Whoa, it's reproducible.](http://ideone.com/k2MsG9) I wasn't expecting that. How the hell?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A fix to your problem would be to put `next(...)` instead of `...` in the return of the third function, or better write `return list((yield from coro()) for i in range(3))` (credits to @zch for this idea), or even better stay with the first function.

---

The point is that the second function is not a generator. It is just an ordinary function that returns a comprehension generator.

For example this code is valid *outside* generator:

```
values = [(yield x) for x in range(3)]
```

Then you can do this:

```
next(values)
0
next(values)
1
next(values)
2
next(values)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration: [None, None, None]
```

Decorator `@coroutine` then makes the second function a generator by iterating over the result, see [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/05e6bab4db8f/Lib/asyncio/coroutines.py), line 143.

On the contrast, the first and the third functions are actually generators, and the `@coroutine` decorator just return themselves, see [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/05e6bab4db8f/Lib/asyncio/coroutines.py), lines 136-137. In first case the generator returns list (actualy raises `StopIteration(['foo', 'foo', 'foo'])`). In the third case it returns the comprehension generator.

Comment: Wait, what does a yield expression do inside a list comprehension, then?

Comment: @user2357112 it makes it a generator and not a list. See `type([(yield x) for x in range(3)])` will give you `<class 'generator'>`. At the same time `type([x for x in range(3)])` is `<class 'list'>`.

Comment: After some digging, I can see why it works the way it does, but this really needs to be a SyntaxError rather than what actually happens. People who know about the behavior won't use it because it's so confusing, and people who don't know about it will get silently wrong code.

Comment: @user2357112 I definitely agree that generators are obscure, but in my opinion they are powerful as well.

Comment: @ivanl, generators are great. The problem is that `yield` inside list comprehension binds to the comprehension, rather than to enclosing function. I would call it a bug.

Comment: @zch I am not sure, but it looks like it has been done from good intensions: "Have list comprehensions be syntactic sugar for passing an equivalent generator expression to list() ; as a consequence the loop variable will no longer be exposed" from PEP3100.

Comment: @ivanl, don't all bugs come from noble intentions? I think the problem is older than PEP3100, it just surfaced thanks to `yield` expressions having value - now it can be useful to `yield` inside an expression. In my opinion `yield` should not refer to generator expression either - nobody expects `list((yield x) for x in range(3))` to return `[0, None, 1, None, 2, None]` (in both python 2 and 3).

Comment: @zch I agree, this would be OK as a workaround (added this to my answer), but no one in good health would use it :)

Comment: I think @zch nailed my source of confusion.  The yield inside the list comprehension binds to the list comprehension rather than the enclosing function.  This seems to be the same issue as this: http://bugs.python.org/issue10544.  Note Guido's response in which he indicates that this is unintuitive behavior and is open to it being changed: http://bugs.python.org/issue10544#msg122759

Comment: @jamesls that is indeed counterintuitive. Lets hope they will fix it in 3.5